# Prestashop Tags are disappearing

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I've developed an ecommerce with Prestashop.

This Prestashop are connect throug a WebAPI's connector with physical store (this connector was developed by the physical store programmers).

Now, the when my customer create a tag, if this tag is not into some product, next day is disappear.

The tags disappear when are not included into any product?
Or maybe happens some strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

When you add a tag from the product, the tags list are updated, removing tags with 0 products (all complete list, all tags).

Is the way presashop works.

I hope is useful to know it.